# How to use setOnTouchListener in C# (Xamarin)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Can you give me an example of setOnTouchListener in C#?

I tried like this but I bring some errors.

```
Button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
        {
            x.Text = "1";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 39):

You either a. use the `Touch` event:

```
button1.Touch += (s, e) =>
{
    var handled = false;
    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
    {
        // do stuff
        handled = true;
    }
    else if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
    {
        // do other stuff
        handled = true;
    }

    e.Handled = handled;
};
```

Or you can explicitly implement the `IOnTouchListener` interface (C# does not have anonymous classes). Note that when implementing Java interfaces, you also need to inherit from `Java.Lang.Object` as we need a handle to the Java side of the story (this is obviously not needed when we use the `Touch` event).

```
public class MyTouchListener 
    : Java.Lang.Object
    , View.IOnTouchListener
{
    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            // do stuff
            return true;
        }
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            // do other stuff
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then set it with:

```
button1.SetOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
```

Note using the latter approach also needs you to handle passing of references to objects that you want to modify in your `OnTouchListener` class, this is not needed with the C# Event.

**EDIT:**
As a side note, if you use the `Touch` event or any other event, please remember to be a good citizen and unhook the event when you are not interested in receiving it anymore. Worst case, if you forget to unhook the event, you will leak memory because the instance cannot be cleaned up.

So in the first example, don't use a anonymous method:

```
button1.Touch += OnButtonTouched;
```

And remember to unhook it:

```
button1.Touch -= OnButtonTouched;
```

Comment: perfect.........! but i noticed that only few people are masters here..lol

Comment: @Cheesebaron Is there anyway to record touches of a view, when the user  touch any children of that view

Comment: @vigneshkumar not exactly sure what you mean. This should probably be a new SO question with more details :)

Answer (score -1):

```
private Button Button1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                // do stuff
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

judging by another question you have asked i am guessing you need to move the onTouch listener into the onCreate method

Comment: please show the errors and all of the oncreate method - edit your question

Comment: I have edited my answer - see above. You may be trying to call the onTouc listner directly from outside the onCreate method this wont work unless you keep it in another method that is still called from OnCreate

Comment: Yes looks like you need to move the method as described above, also you have copied my code directly and you use Button1 i have updated my code to use Button1 not Button

Comment: Check your '}' looks like you either have one to many or need to add one somewhere, post the full file if your still struggling

Comment: See CheeseBarron's comment above about inheriting the java class. I assumed you would have already done this considering you are using the Java interfaces with C# +1 @CheeseBarron